# !Doctype HTML skeleton keyboard shortcut in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

What is the quick keyboard shortcut to get the HTML structure in PhpStorm without having to type out the entire thing?

I have been searching for hours.

Comment: Live Templates (+ Emmet) -- IDE comes with bunch of them. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm

Answer (score 64):

In a HTML context type `!` and press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key in your keyboard:

[image]

it works in php files  too

Answer (score 7):

Just write `!` and press the key `[tab]`, that is all that you need to do, if does not work, check if your file has extension `.html` or `.php`.

I hope it helps you, regards!